# Accessing the value of a IEnumerable mvc2 radio button

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, radio-button, ienumerable

I have a yes/no radio button and need to access the value on another aspx form. I don't know whether I am doing this right or not?

Main viewmodel

```
[UIHint("YesNoEditorTemplate")]
[DisplayName("Are you registered as blind (severely sight impaired)?")]
public IEnumerable<RadioButtonViewModel> RegBlind { get; set; }
```

Radio button viewmodel

```
public class RadioButtonViewModel
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
List<RadioButtonViewModel> regBlindList = new List<RadioButtonViewModel>();
regBlindList.Add(CreateRadioButton("RegBlind", 1, "Yes"));
regBlindList.Add(CreateRadioButton("RegBlind", 0, "No"));
badgeViewModel.RegBlind = regBlindList;
```

Editor Template

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IEnumerable<Tameside.Internal.ViewModels.BlueBadge.RadioButtonViewModel>>"%><%
foreach (var model in Model)
{%>
    <tr>    
        <td><%=String.Format("<input type=\"radio\" id=\"{0}\" name=\"{1}\" value=\"{2}\" />", model.ID, model.Name,model.Value)%></td>
        <td><%=String.Format("<label for=\"{0}\">{1}</label>", model.ID, model.Text)%></td>
    </tr><%
}%>
```

ASPX page

```
<%=Html.EditorFor(x => x.RegBlind)%>
```

Here is how I am accessing the information

```
if (Model.RegBlind.First().Value == 0)
```

Is this correct?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Clare

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that the enumerable will never store the selected value, that's just being lost to a degree.

So you need two parts, one to store the value and another to contain the radio buttons you want to display.

```
[DisplayName("Are you registered as blind (severely sight impaired)?")]
public int RegBlind { get; set; }

public IEnumerable<RadioButtonViewModel> RegBlindOptions { get; set; }
```

Once you've got this sorted, you should be able to use your EditorTemplate as a partial view (though, that'd probably mean moving it out of the EditorTemplates directory and into the appropriate Views folder or shared).

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("YesNoEditorTemplate", Model.RegBlindOptions)%>
```

That should work or be close. If not, have a look at the HTML generated and check everything is there ok, then have a nosey at what is sent back in the POST headers :)